# cross reference a section and equation with color

Tags: sectioning, equations, cross-referencing

I have two issues with this code:
I want to cross-reference an equation as Eq(1) with color 
I want to cross-reference the section as well

any suggestions please, here the code and my outcome :

```
          \documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article} 
                    \usepackage{natbib}
                    \usepackage{amsmath}
                     \usepackage{amsthm} 
                    \usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true]{microtype} 
                   \usepackage{mathpazo} 
                   \usepackage{eucal}
                   \usepackage[mathcal]{eucal}
                    \usepackage[mathscr]{eucal}
                    \usepackage{mathrsfs}
                    \usepackage{lmodern}
                    \usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
                     \usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
                     \usepackage{textcomp}
                     \usepackage{mathtools, cuted}
                      \usepackage{cuted}
                     \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
                     \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
                      \usepackage[english]{babel}
                      \usepackage{booktabs,dcolumn,caption}
                    \usepackage[font=small,labelfont={bf,sf},tableposition=top]{caption}
                     \usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
                              \usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
                               \usepackage{empheq}
                              \usepackage{graphicx}
                               \usepackage{amssymb}
                               \usepackage{mathtools}
                                \usepackage{multirow}
                                 \usepackage{mathtools}
                                  \usepackage{array}
                                  \usepackage{booktabs}
                                  \usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
                                  \usepackage{enumerate}
                                   \usepackage[english]{babel}
                                  \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}     
                                  \usepackage[figurename=Fig.]{caption}
                                   \usepackage{tabulary}
                                    \usepackage{tabularx}
                                    \usepackage{varioref}
                                    \usepackage{multirow}
                                       \usepackage[skip=0.5\baselineskip,font=bf]{caption}
           \usepackage[rm={tabular, lining},sf={tabular, lining},tt{monowidth,tabular,lining {cfr-lm}
                \usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
                  \usepackage{rotating}
                        \usepackage{siunitx}
                       \usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, threeparttable}
                        \usepackage{caption}
                        \usepackage{xparse}    
                         \usepackage{hyperref}
                         \usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev]{cleveref} 
                          \usepackage{xstring}
\hypersetup{colorlinks = true, allcolors = blue}

\makeatletter

  \AtBeginDocument
   {
    \let\oldref\ref
     \renewcommand{\ref}[1]{\IfBeginWith{#1}{fig:}%
      {{\color{blue}Figure~\oldref{#1}}}%
      {\IfBeginWith{#1}{tab:}{{\color{blue}Table~\oldref{#1}}}{Unsupported ref start}}}%
        }
       \makeatother


      \begin{document}


          \begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace]{align}
       Y_{t}    &= c+\sum_{j=1}^{P} \beta_{j}Y_{t-j}+ \sum_{k=1}^{K}b_{k} \widetilde{h}_{t-k}+ 
  \sigma^{*} exp\left({\frac{\widetilde{h_t}}{2}}\right)  \zeta_t  \label{eq:1}\\
  \widetilde{h}_{t} &= \alpha_{t}+\theta \widetilde{h}_{t-1}+\sum_{j=1}^{K} \delta_{j}Y_{t-j}+ \eta_t 
\end{empheq}

   The above equation \Cref{eq:1}, 

  In Section ~\ref{sec:data}, we describe the sample data. 

    \subsection{Data and Variables}
     \label{sec:data}

     \begin{table}[htp]
       \caption{Descriptive statistics}
        \label{tab1}

         \footnotesize
         \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt} 

          \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
        @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
           l
           c
       S[table-format=3.4]
       S[table-format=3.3]
      S[table-format=4.4]
      S[table-format=-1.4]
      S[table-format=1.4]
      S[table-format=3.4]
      S[table-format=3.0]
         @{}
         }
     \toprule
   {Statistic} &
     {Mean} &
     {St. Dev.} &
     {Min} &
     {Max} &
     {Skewness} &
     {Kurtosis} & 
     {Jarque-Bera} &
      {N}\\
     \midrule
     GNP growth (y)          & 0.5531  &   0.7904  &  -2.65  &   2.09   & -1.3202  & 6.1412 &  79.991  
      & 114 \\
   GNP deflator (P)        & 0.6671  &   0.7647  &  -0.16  &   2.72   &  2.0248 & 7.2870 &  165.202 & 114 \\
 Unemployment (U)        & 6.0970  &   1.4535  &   3.90  &  10.53   &  0.9229 & 3.7673 &  18.982  & 114 \\
 BAA corporate bonds (S) & 2.3745  &   0.7904  &   1.08  &   5.82   &  1.5677 & 7.2624 &  133.001  & 114 \\
  House Price index (HPI) & 129.22  &  40.5193  &  75.30  & 202.53   &  0.0184 & 1.5491 &  10.004  & 114 \\
 S\&P 500   index        & 1173.83 & 561.4592  & 317.05  & 2732.58  &  0.4946 & 2.8919 &   4.704  & 114 \\
\bottomrule
 \end{tabular*}
 \end{table}

  Descriptive statistics of variables are given in \Cref{tab1}

 \end{document}
```

the outcome:

[image]

Comment: Please clarify what you intend to achieve by assigning a color to a cross-reference. E.g., should the cross-reference be made into a hyperlink? Or, do you want to assign colors for the sake of assigning colors?

Comment: Off-topic: Many of the instructions in your preamble are either mutually exclusive or redundant. It makes no sense to load the `mathptmx` package and later on the `lmodern` package, as the latter completely overrides the former. And, a few lines later, you load the `cfr-lm` package, which supersedes almost all preceding font-related packages. What exactly do you think you're going to achieve by loading the `mathtools` package three times and the `caption` package a whopping six times? Finally, please confirm that `\usepackage[latin1]{}` is meant to be a joke.

Comment: @Mico I want to assign a blue color when citing a section or equation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote,

> I want to assign a blue color when [cross-referencing] a section or equation.

You've already done most of the work: You're loading the `hyperref` package with the options `colorlinks=true` and `allcolors=blue`, and you're loading the `cleveref` package.

All you need to do now is to use `\cref` and `\Cref` consistently to generate cross-references to objects of type `equation`, `section`, and `table`.

Finally, I can't help but remark that the preamble of your test document is a mess. If this preamble is in any way representative of the preambles in your real documents, I wouldn't be surprised to learn that your documents barely compile. Some suggestions: (1) Don't load packages more than once, and certainly not 3 times or even a whopping 6 times (`caption`). (2) Don't load mutually conflicting and exclusive packages; e.g., there's is no value in loading first the `mathptmx` package, then the `lmodern` package, and then the `cfr-lm` package. Likewise, don't load the `inputenc` package twice -- once with the option `utf8`, the other time with the option `latin1`. (3) Explicitly specifying default options when loading a package, e.g., `protrusion=true,expansion=true` when loading `microtype`, does nothing except create code clutter. (4) Some packages load other packages automatically. For instance, `mathtools` loads `amsmath` automatically; hence, if your document loads the `mathtools` package, there is no need to load `amsmath` exclicitly.

In what follows, I've tried to remove the redundancies and outright conflicts from the preamble. Only you can know for sure if you really need packages such as `cuted`, `xparsse`, and `xstrings`.

[image]

```
  \documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article} 
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage{geometry}

  \usepackage[english]{babel}
  \usepackage{natbib}
  \usepackage{amssymb,mathtools,amsthm} 
  \usepackage{microtype} 
  \usepackage{textcomp}
  \usepackage{cuted}
  \usepackage{dcolumn}
  \usepackage[font=small,
              labelfont={bf,sf},
              tableposition=top,
              skip=0.5\baselineskip,
              font=bf,
              figurename=Fig.,
              justification=centering % that's the default
             ]{caption}
  \usepackage{mathrsfs} % provides \mathscr macro

  \usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
  \usepackage{empheq}
  \usepackage{booktabs}
  \usepackage{enumerate} % don't you want 'enumitem'?
  \usepackage{tabularx,tabulary}
  \usepackage[rm={tabular,lining}, sf={tabular,lining},
              tt={monowidth,tabular,lining}]{cfr-lm}
  \usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
  \usepackage{rotating}
  \usepackage{siunitx}
  \usepackage{makecell,multirow,threeparttable}
  \usepackage{xparse,xstring}   

  \usepackage{varioref}
  \usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
  \usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev]{cleveref} 

\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{2} % just for this example

\begin{equation}\label{eq:1} 1+1=2. \end{equation}
\subsection{Data and Variables} \label{sec:data}
\begin{table}[htp] \caption{Descriptive statistics}\label{tab1} \end{table}

% Finally, some cross-referncing commands:

As shown in \cref{eq:1} above, \dots

In \cref{sec:data}, we describe \dots 

Descriptive statistics are given in \Cref{tab1}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Absolutely fantastic and very professional thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `cleveref` features you should use them consequently.

For changing the cross-reference name `cleveref` provides the `\crefname` and `\Crefname` commands. You will find detailed information about the commands in the official package documentation.

The following example tries to illustrate the use of the commands:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks = true, allcolors = blue}
\usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev]{cleveref} 

\crefname{equation}{eq.}{eq.}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace]{align}
    Y_{t}    &= c+\sum_{j=1}^{P} \beta_{j}Y_{t-j}+ \sum_{k=1}^{K}b_{k} \widetilde{h}_{t-k}+ 
        \sigma^{*} exp\left({\frac{\widetilde{h_t}}{2}}\right)  \zeta_t  \label{eq:1}\\
    \widetilde{h}_{t} &= \alpha_{t}+\theta \widetilde{h}_{t-1}+\sum_{j=1}^{K} \delta_{j}Y_{t-j}+ \eta_t 
\end{empheq}

\Cref{eq:1} is equal to equation \cref{eq:1}.

In ~\cref{sec:data}, we describe the sample data. 

\subsection{Data and Variables}
\label{sec:data}

\begin{table}[htp]
    \caption{Descriptive statistics}\medskip
    \label{tab1}
    \footnotesize
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt} 

    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lcS[table-format=3.4]S[table-format=3.3]S[table-format=4.4]S[table-format=-1.4]S[table-format=1.4]S[table-format=3.4]S[table-format=3.0]@{}}
        \toprule
        {Statistic} & {Mean} & {St. Dev.} & {Min} & {Max} & {Skewness} & {Kurtosis} & {Jarque-Bera} & {N}\\
        \midrule
        GNP growth (y)          & 0.5531  &   0.7904  &  -2.65  &   2.09   & -1.3202  & 6.1412 &  79.991  & 114 \\
        GNP deflator (P)        & 0.6671  &   0.7647  &  -0.16  &   2.72   &  2.0248 & 7.2870 &  165.202 & 114 \\
        Unemployment (U)        & 6.0970  &   1.4535  &   3.90  &  10.53   &  0.9229 & 3.7673 &  18.982  & 114 \\
        BAA corporate bonds (S) & 2.3745  &   0.7904  &   1.08  &   5.82   &  1.5677 & 7.2624 &  133.001  & 114 \\
        House Price index (HPI) & 129.22  &  40.5193  &  75.30  & 202.53   &  0.0184 & 1.5491 &  10.004  & 114 \\
        S\&P 500   index        & 1173.83 & 561.4592  & 317.05  & 2732.58  &  0.4946 & 2.8919 &   4.704  & 114 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular*}
\end{table}

Descriptive statistics of variables are given in \cref{tab1}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think you placed the comment at the wrong place :)